# Empirical PDF and CDF

Tags: probability

I don't have a background in probability, perhaps the following questions are straightforward.

Suppose that $A$ and $B$ are two independent random samples, this two random samples are the output of monte carlo simulation for uncertainty propagation.  The $PDF$ is the empirical distribution function,  and the $CDF$ is the empirical cumulative distribution function. I plot the $PDF$ and the $CDF$.

1. Is there any condition on this two samples $A$ and $B$ to write this?
   $$ PDF(A>B) = PDF(A-B>0) $$
   $$       = 1 -  CDF_{A-B}(0)$$
2. How to calculate the  empirical $PDF$ of $A-B$ from the empirical $PDF$ of $A$ and  the empirical $PDF$ of $B$ ?

Comment: (1) makes no sense at all.  What are you trying to assert? (2) works the same as always: take the convolution of the two PDFs.

Comment: I'm looking to define a stochastic order between two empirical random variables by comparing $P(A>B)$.